# Why does 'this' in a function display window object where as 'this' in an argument displays the object from the function was invoked?

Tags: javascript

Why does 'this' in a function display window object where as 'this' in an argument displays the object from the function was invoked?

```
function show(x){
 alert(x)//displays [object HTMLDivElement]
 alert(this)//displays [object Window]
}

<div onClick="show(this)">123</div>
```

Comment: Go read lots of questions and search the web for "javascript this". -1 as the question doesn't show research effort (lots of sites out there are quite happy to explain it to you if you ask them).

Comment: @ChrisMorgan will do next time.one question though,if I didnt pass this as an argument in function show ,is there a way to get HTMLDivElement object displayed in the function show without passing an ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the function is defined in the global scope, so "this" will refer to the window object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,if I didnt pass this as an argument in function show ,is there a way to get HTMLDivElement object displayed in the function show without passing an ID

Comment: There's a bit more to it than just that.  `obj = { example: function() { alert(this); } }; f = obj.example; f();` should alert '[object Window]' as well.  The rules for `this` are a bit confusing at first.